# Custom Control OnApplyTemplate called only sometimes

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a custom control contained in a WPF Custom Control library where the OnApplyTemplate() method is only called about every other time when I run the debugger in Visual Studio 2012. To be more specific, I've set a break point in the OnApplyTemplate() method, the first time I run the debugger it is never called (and the code I've put inside the method is not executed), but when I select 'Restart' it's called every time.

I've looked at two dozen questions/answers of a similar nature, all advise making sure the DefaultStyleKeyProperty is set in the static constructor (done) and that ResourceDictionaryLocation.None and ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly is set in the AssemblyInfo.cs file (and done).

I've made dozens of custom controls and not had this problem. This is the basic structure:

```
[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_FileTree", Type = typeof(CustomTreeView))]
public class ExplorerComboBox: Control, INotifyPropertyChanged {

        static ExplorerComboBox () {

            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(blinzExplorerComboBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(blinzExplorerComboBox)));

        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate () {

            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            _fileTree = (CustomTreeView)Template.FindName("PART_FileTree", this);
            if (_fileTree != null) {

                _fileTree.SelectedItemChanged += part_fileTree_SelectedItemChanged;
                _fileTree.SelectionMode = SelectionModalities.SingleSelectionOnly;
                try {
                    var drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
                    foreach (var drive in drives) {

                        _fileTree.Items.Add(new FileSystemObjectInfo(drive));

                    }
                } catch  {

                    throw new NotImplementedException();

                }
            } else {

                throw new NotImplementedException();

            }

        }//OnApplyTemplate

}
```

Oddly enough, when OnApplyTemplate is not called, the child CustomTreeView still populates with file information, but the event handler 'SelectedItemChanged' is never set.

Comment: 'blinzExplorerComboBox' seems its ur base type.. Am not sure try it with you control name 'ExploreComboBox'

Comment: That's actually a typo. It reads 'ExplorerComboBox' instead of 'blinzExplorerComboBox' - thanks

Comment: Have you found a solution for that problem?